# Including a custom class in Concrete5 theme

Tags: php, concrete5-5.7

I'm learning Concrete5 and ran into something that has stumped me, but seems like it should be simple to fix.

My class (which resides at \application\src\Derp\Derp.php):

```
namespace Application\Src\Derp;    
use Concrete\Core\Database\Connection\Connection;

class Derp
{   
    return 'Hello';
}
```

I'm calling it from a page in my theme, like so:

```
use Application\Src\Derp;
$derp = new Derp();
var_dump($derp);
```

I keep getting 'An Unexpected Error Occurred'.  Class 'Application\Src\Derp\Derp' not found.  What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reference the path all the way to the class.
So try

```
use Application\Src\Derp\Derp;
```